# Высота скрытого блока

Tags: jquery, css

Как можно определить высоту блока, который лежит в скрытом блоке?

Например:

```css
.outter {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='outter'>
  <div class='inner'>Текст текст текст текст 
текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</div>
</div>
```

Так вот как определить высоту блока `inner` в данном примере?
Функция `$('.inner').height();` всегда выдаёт `0`

Суть в том, что при загрузке странице этот блок скрыт, а открывается он по определенному событию (по клику). Я пытался навешивать ещё один слушатель на клик и в нем вызывать функцию, но `$('.inner').height();`  всё равно выдаёт `0`, т.к. эти слушатели вызываются одновременно и в тот момент времени блок ещё остаётся скрытым

Comment: Если на странице не сильно много элементов и отрисовка не занимает большого количества времени, то можно сперва измерить высоту, а уже после по классу `outer`  задать невидимость для элемента.

Comment: Тоже об этом думал, но проблема в том, что блок скрывается универсальной функцией, используемой повсеместно на сайте, это так называемые табы (вкладки), по клику на кнопку открывается определённая вкладка, так вот нужная мне вкладка всегда скрыта по умолчанию и открывается только по клику на кнопку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы узнать высоту нужно показывать элемент, ок, давайте мы его просто сделаем прозрачным (невидимым), тогда, при клике мы сможем получить высоту и просто убрать прозрачность, вернув его свойства "по дефолту", вот пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
  var cur_height = $('.outter').height();
  $('.outter').css({'position': 'inherit', 'opacity': '1', 'z-index': 'auto'});
  console.log('Высота блока с классом outter = ' + cur_height);
});
```

```css
.outter {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='outter'>
  <div class='inner'>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</div>
</div>

<button id="btn">А нука покажись!</button>
```

Comment: Я пытался сделать что-то подобное, чтобы вместо display: none использовать прозрачность и абсолютное позиционирование, но есть одна загвоздка: такой блок хоть и не виден, но всё же занимает определенное пространство, и если в нём много контента, внизу страницы образуется огромный пробел

Comment: Проблема, описанная в комментарии выше, решилась установкой на родительский элемент position: relative и overflow: hidden  спасибо за оперативный ответ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, высота элемента 0, так как у родителя высота 0, если хотите узнать высоту блока просто  удалите display:none у родителя и после этого вызовите .height() .